# Use Haml files in Redmine plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, plugins, haml, redmine, rails-engines

I am creating a Redmine plugin and would like to use Haml for the view templates.  There is an existing plugin which has Haml views ([ekanban](https://github.com/samchen2009/ekanban)) and it does not contain any special code to get Haml working other then having you add `require 'haml'` to your main application's `Gemfile`.

So here is what happens -- the templating system loads the `.html.haml` file correctly but renders the HAML markup (like it was rendering ERB).

I've tried to insert the `require 'haml'` at various intervals to no avail.  I've even tried manually trying to activate `Haml.init_rails(...)` as suggested in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988760/how-do-i-use-haml-in-a-view-in-my-new-plugin).  I've tried inserting that in a few places, tried it in a `Rails.configuration.to_prepare` block in the plugins' `init.rb` file.  I've tried telling the Gemfile to not `require 'haml'` and attempting to do it during plugin load to no avail.  What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view template had Textile in it and I did not notice because the markup for `<h2>` is similar (`h2.` vs. `%h2`).  Including `gem 'haml_rails'` in the plugin's `Gemfile` is sufficient with no extra code.

Answer (score 0):

Read carefully [Installation instruction](https://github.com/samchen2009/ekanban#installation-instructions) for this gem :)

> Add "gem 'haml'" to your #{RAILS_ROOT}/Gemfile

I can't agree with this strategy: plugin can't change Redmine core! Any Redmine plugin can have own gems (defined in own `Gemfile`) - so I think you can create `Gemfile` in your plugin, run `bundle install` from the Redmine root and I believe you will manage to use Haml

Comment: I did put `gem 'haml'` in `${RAILS_ROOT}/Gemfile` originally as mentioned in the first paragraph.  I also tried defining it in the plugin's `Gemfile`.  Same issue.

Comment: have you run `bundle install` after changing in Gemfile?

Comment: Yeah, as is standard procedure when adding things to the Gemfile